# Hibernate resource pool closing too soon

Tags: hibernate, jpa, c3p0

I am performing stress tests on our database, which is hibernate on MySQL.  I'm using the c3p0 connection pool with default configuration except for a maxpoolsize of 15.

```
interface EntityRepository extends JpaRepository<Entity, UUID> {}

@Service
public class EntityService {

    @Autowired
    EntityRepository er;

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public Entity addEntity(Entity r) {
        er.save(r);
    }
}

public class StressTest {

    @Autowired
    EntityService rs;

    @Test
    public void entityStressTest() {
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    rs.addEntity(new Entity());
                }
            }
            t.start();
        }
    }
}
```

Each time I run this test I create 5-8 entities, and then I receive one of the following three log messages:

[ERROR] 14:39:23,127 [Thread-20] SqlExceptionHelper - An SQLException was provoked by the following failure: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.ResourcePoolException: Attempted to use a closed or broken resource pool

[ INFO] 14:48:45,478 [Thread-11] JdbcTransaction - HHH000425: Could not close session; swallowing exception[org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.stat.spi.StatisticsImplementor]] as transaction completed

[ INFO] 14:49:22,860 [Thread-18] BasicResourcePool - com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@16f7ca -- an attempt to checkout a resource was interrupted, because the pool is now closed. [Thread: Thread-18]

I am stumped as to what could be causing this

Comment: hi. i've no idea what's causing the problem, but somewhere along the line something is calling close() on the underlying resource pool when you'd rather it not. Do you have any c3p0-related [package com.mchange.v2.resourcepool] output in your logs at level SEVERE? If the pool shutdown internally because of an unexpected problem, there would be. (BTW, what version of c3p0 are you using?) Otherwise, you need to track down what external thing is explicitly close()ing the pool.

Comment: If it'd help, I can come up with a debug version that logs a stack trace on pool close. ("Pool close" should be a very rare event: Connections come and go, but pools usually survive the full uptime of their application.) For my e-mail, see c3p0's docs, http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a race condition; that's what's causing the closed connection pool error.

In your test method you're creating new threads that asynchronously are using your connection pool but the test method itself is not waiting for them to complete. Thus it's possible (and I guess with 100 threads highly likely) that some of them haven't completed by the time the test method completes. After your test method completes, Spring is closing the connection pool and thus when a thread subsequently tries to use the pool it'll error out.

If you turn on `DEBUG` (or possibly `TRACE`) logging for the logger `org.springframework` and add a log statement to your `addEntity(...)` method you should see it getting called after the test method is complete and the connection pool bean destruction has taken place.

To fix this use a CountDownLatch to have the main test method wait for the threads to complete there work before returning:

```
@Test
public void entityStressTest() {
    int numThreads = 100;
    final CountDownLatch counter = new CountDownLatch(numThreads);
    for(int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++) {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                rs.addEntity(new Entity());
                counter.countDown();
            }
        }
        t.start();
    }
    counter.await();
}
```